# How to search entire domain for a user in AD using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, ldap

I understand how to find a user using the exact LDAP url

```
LDAP://domain/CN=Username,OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com
```

but what if I need to find a user without looking in the particular OU. How do I search the entire domain?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using .NET 3.5 or newer, you should check out the `PrincipalSearcher` class:

```
' create your domain context
Dim ctx As New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)

' define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a UserPrincipal 
' and with the first name (GivenName) of "Bruce" and a last name (Surname) of "Miller"
Dim qbeUser As New UserPrincipal(ctx)
qbeUser.GivenName = "Bruce"
qbeUser.Surname = "Miller"

' create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
Dim srch As New PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser)

' find all matches
For Each found As var In srch.FindAll()
    ' do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer.....          
Next
```

If you haven't already - absolutely read the MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) which shows nicely how to make the best use of the new features in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`. Or see the [MSDN documentation on the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx) namespace.

Of course, depending on your need, you might want to specify other properties on that "query-by-example" user principal you create:

- `DisplayName` (typically: first name + space + last name)
- `SAM Account Name` - your Windows/AD account name
- `User Principal Name` - your "username@yourcompany.com" style name

You can specify any of the properties on the `UserPrincipal` and use those as "query-by-example" for your `PrincipalSearcher`.

Or if you want to find just a specific user - try this:

```
' find a user
Dim user As UserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName")

' do something here....     
If user IsNot Nothing Then
   . .....
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Just omit the OU structure from the LDAP path. This will set the search at the root of the domain.

```
LDAP://DC=domain,DC=com
```

and use a filter to find the specific user:

```
(&(objectClass=User)(cn=" & susername & "))
```

Comment: Note that the search scope should be `sub` in this example.

Comment: So using Tom Pickles' suggestion, I came up with this